# Why does my iPhone have to be within an inch of a device to tether?

Tags: ios, tethering

We have home internet issues and have had to tether our iMacs, Macbooks, and Nintendo Switches to our iPhones or iPads for an internet connection.  I set up my iPhone for tethering by turning wifi on and turning on the hotspot.  I am able to successfully connect to the internet on our other devices by tethering to my iPhone.

The issue is that I find my iPhone has to be within about 1" of my other device for anything to connect to the iPhone wifi to use it as a hotspot.  For instance, if I hold my Switch and iPhone so the iPhone is against the back of the Switch, I can tether successfully.  With my iMac, if I have my iPhone near it, I can't connect.  But if I hold my iPhone within 1" of the right side of my iMac's screen, and, even then, it has to be on the right side of the screen, a bit below the center, I can connect.

Once connected (with a Switch or my iMac), I no longer have to keep the devices together.  But I can never make the connection unless my iPhone is in just the right place, relative to the other device.

Why does my iPhone need to be almost touching something for me to successfully create a tethering connection?

Addendum:

My wife and I are using 3 tethering devices (my iPhone, her iPhone, and my iPad) and 4 other devices (my iMac, my Switch, her iMac, and her Switch Lite.  While it's been similar with her Macbook, we haven't done much testing with it).  We've also done this in our house, with one kind of wifi (Deco M9) and in our barn (out of wifi range) with a different wifi hub.  (I tried several brands down there for other reasons, but it was still the same issue.)

So I don't think it can be a problem with one tethering device or one other device or with the local wifi.

Comment: The iPhone shouldn't have to be that close for the hotspot to work.  I've successfully connected devices to my iPhone X from different parts of my house.  It could be because of wifi interference or such a poor signal that the connecting devices can't get a clear signal unless they're right on top of the source device (your iPhone).

Comment: @fsb: It strikes me as odd it has to be that close, too - but it's true with my iPad, too.  If I use it as a hotspot, it's the same.  My wife has the same issue with her iMac and her Switch.  So I would say my iPhone must have a weak signal, but three tether devices (my iPhone and iPad and my wife's iPhone) have this issue with 4 devices (2 iMacs and 2 Switches - one Switch Lite and one "big" Switch). Tried the Switches in two locations, too. Also, if the signal were so weak, it it seems odd that once the connection is established the devices don't have to be so close.

Comment: You did a lot of good troubleshooting but I don't have any idea what the problem could be.  Hopefully, someone will be able to provide more help than I have.

Comment: @fsb: Thank you.  Yeah, I'm hoping the same thing.  At least it works, it's just such a weird issue to deal with.  On the other hand, I got a tracking number from our ISP and the SIM chip they're sending us is out for delivery (via UPS), so we won't have to be tethering much longer.  (We have cellular internet because we're in a rural area.  AT&T upgraded and bricked a lot of modems.  That left us without internet for 8 days.  The new modem worked 2 weeks and then the SIM chip "expired" this week.)